# How can I change the connection from Datasource Wizard on runtime?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datasource, config

Is it possible to change the connection String of a dataset which is made by the configuration wizard?

As I started the project I  created all connections to the DevelopmentDatabase, now at the end of my Project my Mentor said to me I shall not only replace the connections with a connection to the productive system, instead the tool shall have both Databases in option?

The problem is, that I have created almost all connections with the wizard, that´s why I cant just change it via a variable.

I dont know what code to post, I guess it is not needed at this point.

Cheers Beckstar101

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that to answer your question I assumed that this is a Windows Forms Application; However if i am right, your Windows application can have an optional app.config file (right-click project in Solution Explorer and select Add. Then click General to the left and locate "Application Configuration File". Select it and Click the Add button. Voila!).

Now you can add your connection string in the same way you do it in a web application.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to store the connection string for your application in a config file rather than as a hard coded string in your code. The way to do this differs between .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 (and above). This article covers  .NET 3.5 (and above).

You can use the connectionStrings section in web.config file to store your and manage your connectionStrings. See sample below.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

To read the connection string into your code, use the ConfigurationManager class.

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Hello again Warrior, this article shows me, how to store and where to store the connection String and also how to read it into code. But I still dont know how i can use this, to change the connectionstring of my datasource. The connection String is saved in my.settings and is read only?